# A constraint that only allows one of two tables to reference a base table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

I have 3 tables. A base table, call it Table A, and two tables that reference Table A, Call them Table X and Table Y. Both X and Y have a foreign key contraint that references Table A. The Foreign Key of X and Y is also their own Primary Key.

I'd like to know if it is possible to add a constraint that will only allow one of these tables to contain a recrod that references Table A. So if X has a record that references A then Y can't have one and if Y has a record that references A then X can't have one.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I'd be curious about your use case. There is something __interesting__ about your structure. You have 3 primary keys using the same key value.

Comment: Yes they are three tables for storing user accounts. There are two types of account. So there is a base table that contains info that is common to both type of account and then a table for each account type that holds info specific to that account type. So the PK for each table is the UserID because I figured this would make things coherent and make accessing a record by UserID easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CHECK constraints with UDFs (which is Oded's answer) don't scale well and have poor concurrency. See these:

- [Scalar UDFs wrapped in CHECK constraints are very slow and may fail for multirow updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx)
- [Tony Rogerson](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/02/07/using-a-udf-in-a-check-constraint-to-check-validity-of-history-windows-start-end-date-windows.aspx)

So:

- create a new table, say TableA2XY
- this has the PK of TableA and a char(1) column with a CHECK to allow ony X or Y. And a unique constraint on the PK of A too.
- tableX and tableY have new char(1) column with a check to allow only X or Y respectively
- tableX and tableY have their FK to TableA2XY on both columns

This is the superkey or subtype approach

- all [DRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_Referential_Integrity) based
- no triggers
- no udfs with table access in CHECK constraints.

Comment: I am doing pretty much the same thing as what you have described. Recently I switched to adding a persisted computed CHAR(1) column in my child table, so that it does not show up in column lists automatically generated by SQL Prompt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using [CHECK constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx).

Apart from the normal foreign key constraint, you will need to add a [CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) on both referencing tables to ensure that a foreign key is not used in the other referencing table.

Comment: The CHECK needs a scalar udf which is not safe and slow. See my answer please.