# SQL Table Organization

Tags: sql, database-design

I have verious accounts which need to be kept track of. These accounts are all very similar having fields such as:

```
account_number, date_opened, current_expenditure etc.
```

Now, these accounts are of three types (we'll call them Type A, B, C) 
Each of these account types requires at least one other field, unique to it's type. For example:

```
Type A: account_number, date_opened, current_expenditure, owner
Type B: account_number, date_opened, current_expenditure, location
Type C: account_number, date_opened, current_expenditure, currency
```

My question is whether or not I should combine these into one large table, with a column denoting account type (leaving irrelevant fields empty):

```
Table 1: accounts
Table 2: accts_emp_maps

Account Columns: 
account_number, type, date_opened, current_expenditure, owner, location, currency
```

Or, should I have an individual table for each account type? Keep in mind that there will be other tables mapping employees to these accounts. If I split up the accounts into different types, I will need to split the maps as well. IE:

```
Table 1: A_accounts
Table 2: A_accts_emp_maps
Table 3: B_accounts
Table 4: B_accts_emp_maps
Table 5: C_accounts
Table 6: C_accts_emp_maps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the one table approach, with `owner, location, currency`, extra columns. It'll make your life easier.

If it gets too large, you can partition it by type.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But I have to balance doing it the "right way" and doing it the logical/easy way

Answer (score 1):

Classically, you'd maybe use the superkey/subtype pattern for this to ensure only one of owner, location, currency

- One table with common columns and a type column
- Unique super key on the PK + type (A, B or C) column
- Three child tables with key of PK + type. This is where you add specific columns
- Check constraint on the child type constraints to limit to A, B or C in the child tables

Now, in this case I'd consider having redundant columns for simplicity though

Examples:

- [A constraint that only allows one of two tables to reference a base table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323932/a-constraint-that-only-allows-one-of-two-tables-to-reference-a-base-table/6323980#6323980)
- (DBA.SE) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4105/database-schema-with-a-shared-identity-field/4110#4110
- [Database design - articles, blog posts, photos, stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-problem/4970646#4970646)

Answer (score -1):

Of the two options you have listed, I would definitely pick the first one.  It will be fine for most applications, and the tables will be simpler to query manually.  (The second proposed design duplicates a lot of information among the three sets of account tables).

However, depending on your needs, a [more normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) database design which may be better is something like this:

```
Table: accounts
===============
number, type, date_opened, current_expenditure

Table: account_owners
=====================
account_number, owner

Table: account_currencies
=========================
account_number, currency

Table: account_locations
========================
account_number, location
```

Comment: You now have the problem of enforcing exactly one row in one of the child tables